# Alter Value of Material Slide Toggle based on user response to javascript 'confirm'

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, slidetoggle

I am implementing an Angular Material Slide Toggle.  If the user is switching the toggle from true to false, I would like to show a confirmation making sure they want to do this.  If they say cancel, I would like to keep the slide toggle set to true.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's the html of the component:

```
<md-slide-toggle checked="checked" (change)="changeEvent($event)">Slide Toggle</md-slide-toggle>
```

And the component's typescript:

```
changeEvent(ev) {
    if (ev.checked === false) {
      var x = confirm("Are you sure?")
      if (!x) {
        return ev.checked === false; 
      }
    }
  }
```

And here's a plunker demonstrating what I have so far...http://plnkr.co/edit/WP55vlFQBljgKM0jkf2R?p=preview

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist, set a model for the slider and change the name ('checked' seems causing an issue). Also use [] for the `checked` attribute. Then set that value to true or false when canceling or affirming in the dialog box. Otherwise `ev.checked` value is getting 'lost', it doesn't do anything:

**HTML:**

```
<md-slide-toggle [checked]="myValue" (change)="changeEvent($event)">Slide Toggle</md-slide-toggle>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
... 
if (ev.checked === false) {
      var x = confirm("Are you sure?")
      if (!x) {
        this.myValue = true; 
      }
}
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mXam6KDTpzz98j95NOEB?p=preview)**